# is it possible for android not to enter the OnDestroy() method and keep the app runing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hello guys i'm using xamarin forms 
i have a class LocalNotif wish content notification calls 
on IOS devices i manage to fetch the device even when the app is destroyed but in Android i don't know how 
can any one help please.
Thank you

Comment: Its a life cycle method my friend it will happen no matter what you do, It's not like you can say no I do not want it!

Comment: As a side note, be sure to review what you did on iOS, to make sure that it won't eventually lead to your app being terminated without warning. [Apple doc re background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the app running in the background you need to create a service.

A service runs in the background (even after closing the app) and provides info for the application, for example when playing a song in Spotify and it keeps playing even after closing the app, notification from Facebook, etc.

I don't think that it's possible to not enter OnDestroy(), but you can read further about services [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

Comment: On iOS since forever and Android as of Nougat I think (or Oreo, don't know) this is quite restricted. iOS will allow only certain types of apps and you will be rejected if you - for example - pretend to play a song which is silent to keep the app alive (people used to do that back in the days) and with Android you'll need a foreground activity that's always visible in the notification hub.